# Doctrine: use user defined function in ORDERBY

Tags: symfony, if-statement, doctrine, sql-order-by

What I want to achieve is something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY (IF ranking IS NULL, 9999, ranking) ASC
```

So, I need an if in my `orderby`. But it seems that user defined functions (I created one named ComplexIf) are not working in OrderBy.

```
->addOrderBy('ComplexIf(u.ranking IS NULL, 9999, u.ranking )', 'asc')
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure about your actual question, but have you tried using `CASE` instead of `IF`? See [this answer on another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14107313/1001110) which suggests it should work in Doctrine.

Comment: Thank you! that was exactly what I needed, I finally made it work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks SO MUCH to Nic, I finally found the solution with a CASE instead of an IF!

```
$query = $this
            ->createQueryBuilder( 'a' )
            ->select('a')
            ->add('from', 'path\to\whatever\table a')
            ->addSelect('CASE WHEN a.ranking IS NULL THEN 9999 ELSE a.ranking END as HIDDEN ORD')
            ->where( 'a.deleted IS NULL' )
            ->orderBy(  'ORD', 'asc' )
            ->getQuery()
            ;
```