# Converting sql to dql

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

I have a problem converting a sql query to dql. 
Can anyone help me.

This is what i got so far:

```
$query = $this->em->createQuery("
        UPDATE MyBundle:Tree AS n
        JOIN MyBundle:Tree AS movingNode ON movingNode.id = :node
        JOIN MyBundle:Tree AS parentNode ON parentNode.id = :parent
        SET
        n.lft = n.lft +
            IF (parentNode.lft < movingNode.lft,
                 IF (n.lft >= movingNode.rgt + 1, 0,
                        IF (n.lft >= movingNode.lft, parentNode.lft - movingNode.lft + 1,
                                IF (n.lft >= parentNode.lft + 1, movingNode.rgt - movingNode.lft + 1 , 0
                                    )
                            )
                     ),
                 IF (n.lft >= parentNode.lft + 1, 0,
                        IF (n.lft >= movingNode.rgt + 1, -movingNode.rgt + movingNode.lft - 1,
                                IF (n.lft >= movingNode.lft, parentNode.lft - movingNode.rgt, 0
                                    )
                            )
                     )
                ),
        n.rgt = n.rgt +
            IF (parentNode.lft < movingNode.lft,
                 IF (n.rgt >= movingNode.rgt + 1, 0,
                        IF (n.rgt >= movingNode.lft, parentNode.lft - movingNode.lft + 1,
                                IF (n.rgt >= parentNode.lft + 1, movingNode.rgt - movingNode.lft + 1 , 0
                                    )
                            )
                     ),
                 IF (n.rgt >= parentNode.lft + 1, 0,
                        IF (n.rgt >= movingNode.rgt + 1, -movingNode.rgt + movingNode.lft - 1,
                                IF (n.rgt >= movingNode.lft, parentNode.lft - movingNode.rgt, 0
                                    )
                            )
                     )
                )
        WHERE parentNode.lft < movingNode.lft OR parentNode.lft > movingNode.rgt;
    ")->setParameter('node', $node)->setParameter('parent', $parent);
```

It seems like i need to split it into subquerys or in more querys. Iam not shure.

Also it seems like there isent support for update and join in dql.

Comment: I don't believe Doctrine can handle `if` cases like you want. I would either use ORM (i.e. your `Tree` entity instances, through their getters/setters, but it's not a flexible as native SQL for this scenario) or native SQL as described here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html

Comment: Have a look to nested set implementations in doctrine2 : https://wildlyinaccurate.com/simple-nested-sets-in-doctrine-2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CASE` instead of `IF` or you could create your own custom IF DQL function. If you did a bit of searching you probably could have already found your answer.

Here's a post that describes those:
[Converting MySQL to Doctrine Query Builder. Issues with IF and CONCAT. Or another approach for subqueries on select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14098219/converting-mysql-to-doctrine-query-builder-issues-with-if-and-concat-or-anothe)

Also, using `UPDATE` in your Doctrine query doesn't seem like the right thing to do since normally Doctrine takes care of updates. You may want to reconsider your design.